# cap deployment not finding rbenv ruby version when it appears to be there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, capistrano, rbenv

I am running an ubuntu instance on AWS with rails 2.5.8, and using capistrano to deploy. I recently switched from rvm to rbenv on my instance and am trying to get capistrano to deploy successfully. When I run 'cap production deploy', I get the following error:

```html
Kevins-MacBook-Pro:ewagers kevinsun$ cap production deploy
00:00 rbenv:validate
      WARN  rbenv: 2.5.8 is not installed or not found in $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8 on 3.133.135.38
```

This is confusing because when I ssh into my instance to check, I can confirm that it really is present:

```html
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-163:~$ cd $HOME/.rbenv/versions
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-163:~/.rbenv/versions$ ls
2.5.8
```

I have configured capistrano::rbenv as directed. Here is my Capfile:

```ruby
# Load DSL and set up stages

require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/sidekiq'
require "whenever/capistrano"
require 'capistrano/sidekiq/monit'


install_plugin Capistrano::Puma  # Default puma tasks
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Workers  # if you want to control the workers (in cluster mode)
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Monit 
# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Here is my deploy.rb file:

```ruby
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
#lock '3.8.1'

#require "rvm/capistrano"

# application, repo, and branch info ommitted


set :user,            'deploy'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    4

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             false
set :use_sudo,        false
set :sidekiq_user,    fetch(:user)
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord
# set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.5.8@wager'
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'puma.rb', 'config/app.yml', "config/sidekiq.yml", "config/env.yml")
set :sidekiq_config, 'config/sidekiq.yml'
# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system'
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads', 'public/watir')
## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
set :keep_releases, 2
set :execute_monit_without_sudo, false
## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
    desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
    task :make_dirs do
        on roles(:app) do
            execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
            execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
        end
    end

    before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
    desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
    task :check_revision do
        on roles(:app) do
            unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/#{fetch(:branch)}`
                puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/#{fetch(:branch)}"
                puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
                exit
            end
        end
    end

    desc 'Initial Deploy'
    task :initial do
        on roles(:app) do
            before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
            invoke 'deploy'
        end
    end

    desc 'Restart application'
    task :restart do
        on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
            invoke 'puma:restart'
        end
    end


    before :starting,     :check_revision
    after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
    after  :finishing,    :cleanup
    after  :finishing,    :restart

end

namespace :deploy do
    desc "Update crontab with whenever"
    task :update_cron do
        on roles(:app) do
            within current_path do
                execute :bundle, :exec, "whenever --update-crontab #{fetch(:application)}"
            end
        end
    end

    after :finishing, 'deploy:update_cron'
end

namespace :deploy do
    desc 'run "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pgcrypto"" in sudo mode'
    task :sudo_pgcrypto do
        on roles(:all) do |host|
            execute :sudo, "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS", "pgcrypto"
        end
    end
end

namespace :logs do
  desc "tail rails logs" 
  task :puma do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "tail -f -n 500 #{shared_path}/log/#{fetch(:rails_env)}.log "
    end
  end
end
# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma

set :rbenv_type, :user # or :system, or :fullstaq (for Fullstaq Ruby), depends on your rbenv setup
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.5.8'

# in case you want to set ruby version from the file:
# set :rbenv_ruby, File.read('.ruby-version').strip

set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}
set :rbenv_roles, :all # default value
```

Comment: Hi. you can upload `deploy.rb` file? Maybe you missing `set :rbenv_ruby, '2.5.8'` this is docs of gem [capistrano-rbenv](https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv)

Comment: Hey Korgi, uploaded the whole thing. I followed that capistrano-rbenv doc for setting up :)